# Need help getting simple node.js express to run

Tags: node.js, eclipse

I'm trying a simple sample of node express that I copied from online. The script is below which I think is pretty standard.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response)){
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.write("hello");
    response.end();
}).listen(8080);

console.log('listening on port 8080...');
```

I used the bash on ubuntu on windows command as follows:

## npm init

## node SampleServer.js (the name of my file)

When I do this, I expect some response from the command line. But when I enter the "node SamplerServer.js" command, nothing happens. When I direct the browser to port 8080, I get an error message as well.

I'm using nodeclipse and the installing that on my machine was pretty complicated. Prior to any of the steps above, I created an express project in eclipse ide. It seems to perform a lot of pre steps but in the end, I think I'm getting some of the error messages below. I'm mentioning this because I'm thinking perhaps I installed one of the modules wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoexS.png)

Comment: What you expect from command line?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is but I'm thinking I'm duplicating my efforts here by npm init as well as creating a new project in nodeclipse, no?

Comment: You can use any text editor to make your .js files; Atom is nice if you are on a Mac.  Every node app beyond hello world has a route handler, so you can render different code at `localhost:8080/` and `localhost:8080/stuff/` ... it looks like your basis setup for node is a bit funky; try just installing node and using a simple text editor like sublime text to make your js files in your project folder(s).  Please check out http://nodeschool.io/ !! great stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with simple stuff...

Use [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) to create `simple` app by the following command

1-> `npm install -g express-generator` with `root` or `Admin` access

2-> Run `express demoapp`.

3-> Navigate to `demoapp`

4-> Do `npm install`

5-> Run from command with `npm start`: it run by default on  `http://localhost:3000`

Hit that `URL` from `Browser`

Comment: Thanks. Follow-up question, do I need nodeclipse at all? I feel like that is totally redundant.

Comment: I ask because I think using command line coupled with note++ should be sufficient, I think.

Comment: Not really required it totally depends everyone favourites. you can use `Sublime2 or 3` and `WebStorm` which is mostly used while working with `MEAN` app

Comment: ok, I installed -g express-generator from root. It seems like it adds a set of files inside a folder called "testexpress". From there I'm lost.

Comment: It creates a `simple app` with some files and folder with simple startup

Comment: i'm typing "node app.js" from the bash CLI from the testexpress directory but get nothing :(

Comment: Do `npm start` or if you want to use `node app.js`, put this line code in your `app.js` file `app.listen(5000)` and hit `http://localhost:5000`

Comment: does the actual port number make a difference? I tried npm start, got nothing. I then went into the app.js file and changed the port 3000 to 5000. Got nothing. I feel like I installed something wrong. urg.

Comment: Follow the `answer` in right way, I'm sure you will not stuck.

Comment: So, thanks for the help, think your answer worked. I find out that my bash on ubuntu on windows does not work which was what I was using as my command line. When I used the normal windows CMD, it worked, now I just get different set of errors which I can work with. I'm seriously thinking of just getting mac at this point.

Comment: I wanted to add one more comment. I got the node app to work on the browser. This was only after I fixed the layoutjade file because the first line was "!!!" which had to be fixed to "doctype html". npm is so hard to use in my opinion.